# Can I ask which answer to choose between multiple great answers?

Tags: discussion

I have a programming question, and people gave me multiple answers, and each works great for me. But I do want to choose the best answer due to its efficiency, except I do not know which is more efficient. Can I ask a new question for comparing the answers given to me?

Comment: You may find out using comments.

Comment: This is a legit answer... Please write it in an answer! :)

Comment: Also note you don't need to accept any of the answers, if all of them helped you equally good.

Comment: You need to try the solutions yourself and see how they perform.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I really don't know which one to choose. I will wait a bit and i'll follow the community upvotes and check the most upvoted.